# Ubuntu 13.10 Server : wget changes the filename of downloaded file automatically

Tags: command-line, 13.10, scripts, wget

I have a simple shell script on my Ubuntu 13.10 Server to download all files in a list.

```
filen="/home/chester/test/workobject.txt"
dir_log="/home/chester/test"

if [ -f "$filen" ]
then
cd $dir_log
for n in `cat $filen`
   do
     echo $n
     wget -O $n.txt -q http://domain.com/QuickSearch?object=$n&search=Overview
   done
else
   echo "Nothing to do."
fi
```

The contents of `workobject.txt`:

```
9957881
9A39879
```

The script works properly. However, when it downloads the `9957881.txt` files, it changes the filename to `9Z44X7~P.txt` instead.

What is wrong with the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a check on the output and it shows a `%0D` on the filename. Upon more research, I have found out that this is the trailing line break on the `workobject.txt`. Sadly, I cannot do anything about the formatting of `workobject.txt` file because it is only being pushed to my server via `scp`.

I just let the script do the same thing and just batch rename all the files after processing to remove the `%0D` trailing the filename.

So the final script looks like this:

```
filen="/home/chester/test/workobject.txt"
dir_log="/home/chester/test"

if [ -f "$filen" ]
then
cd $dir_log
for n in `cat $filen`
   do
     wget -q http://domain.com/QuickSearch?object=$n
   done
else
   echo "Nothing to do."
fi
rename "s/%0D//g" Quick*
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use:

```
wget -O - -q http://domain.com/QuickSearch?object=$n&search=Overview > $n.txt
```

See `man wget` to understand why.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it also gives me the same output. I have already figured it out so I will answer the question.

Comment: Please do it. It will be probably useful for other users.